# Fetching specific parameter from XML response in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to get the "ModelYear" parameter from this xml but without succcess, I need help to know where is the problem please.

here is the XML: 
https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVinValues/3FA6P0RU6HR216769?format=xml

and here is my code: as you can see I'm trying to fetch the value of "ModelYear" and assign it as innerHTML for another element, using a script

```
var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
  document.getElementById("decode_yr").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ModelYear");
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` returns `NodeList`

You need to get the first `Node` out of the same and get its `nodeValue`

```
document.getElementById("decode_yr").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ModelYear")[0].nodeValue;
```

**Demo**

```js
var xml = `<Response>
<Count>116</Count>
<Message>Results returned successfully</Message>
<SearchCriteria>VIN(s): 3FA6P0RU6HR216769</SearchCriteria>
<Results>
<DecodedVINValues>
<VIN>3FA6P0RU6HR216769</VIN>
<BatteryInfo/>
<BatteryType/>
<BedType/>
<BodyCabType/>
<BodyClass>Sedan/Saloon</BodyClass>
<Country/>
<EngineCylinders>4</EngineCylinders>
<DestinationMarket/>
<DisplacementCC>2000.0</DisplacementCC>
<DisplacementCI>122.04748818946</DisplacementCI>
<DisplacementL>2.0</DisplacementL>
<Doors>4</Doors>
<DriveType/>
<DriverAssist/>
<EngineCycles/>
<EngineModel>2.0L 4V AtK HEV</EngineModel>
<EngineKW>140.1916</EngineKW>
<EntertainmentSystem/>
<FuelTypePrimary>Gasoline</FuelTypePrimary>
<GVWR/>
<Make>FORD</Make>
<Manufacturer>FORD MOTOR COMPANY, MEXICO</Manufacturer>
<Model>Fusion</Model>
<ModelYear>2017</ModelYear>
<PlantCity>Hermosillo</PlantCity>
<Seats/>
<Series>Titanium HEV</Series>
<SteeringLocation/>
<TransmissionStyle/>
<Trim/>
<VehicleType>PASSENGER CAR</VehicleType>
<Windows/>
<Axles/>
<BrakeSystemType/>
<NCICCode/>
<BatteryCells/>
<BedLengthIN/>
<BrakeSystemDesc/>
<CurbWeightLB/>
<AirBagLocCurtain/>
<AirBagLocSeatCushion/>
<BatteryA/>
<BatteryV/>
<BatteryKWh/>
<WheelBaseType/>
<SeatRows/>
<ValveTrainDesign/>
<TransmissionSpeeds/>
<EngineConfiguration>In-Line</EngineConfiguration>
<AirBagLocFront>1st Row (Driver & Passenger)</AirBagLocFront>
<FuelTypeSecondary>Electric</FuelTypeSecondary>
<FuelInjectionType/>
<AirBagLocKnee>1st Row (Driver & Passenger)</AirBagLocKnee>
<EngineHP>188</EngineHP>
<EVDriveUnit/>
<PlantCountry>Mexico</PlantCountry>
<PlantCompanyName>Hermosillo</PlantCompanyName>
<PlantState/>
<Pretensioner/>
<SeatBeltsAll>Manual</SeatBeltsAll>
<AdaptiveCruiseControl/>
<AdaptiveHeadlights/>
<ABS/>
<AEB/>
<BlindSpotMon/>
<CAFEBodyType/>
<CAFEMake/>
<CAFEModel/>
<NCAPBodyType/>
<NCAPMake/>
<NCAPModel/>
<NCSABodyType/>
<NCSAMake/>
<NCSAModel/>
<ESC/>
<TractionControl/>
<ForwardCollisionWarning/>
<LaneDepartureWarning/>
<LaneKeepSystem/>
<RearVisibilityCamera/>
<ParkAssist/>
<AirBagLocSide>1st & 2nd Rows</AirBagLocSide>
<Artemis/>
<Trim2/>
<Series2/>
<WheelBaseShort/>
<WheelBaseLong/>
<Note/>
<Wheels/>
<TrailerType/>
<TrailerBodyType/>
<TrailerLength/>
<WheelSizeFront/>
<WheelSizeRear/>
<OtherRestraintSystemInfo/>
<CoolingType/>
<EngineHP_to/>
<ElectrificationLevel>Strong Hybrid</ElectrificationLevel>
<ChargerLevel/>
<ChargerPowerKW/>
<OtherEngineInfo/>
<BatteryA_to/>
<BatteryV_to/>
<BatteryKWh_to/>
<Turbo/>
<BasePrice/>
<BatteryModules/>
<BatteryPacks/>
<TopSpeedMPH/>
<EquipmentType/>
<ManufacturerType/>
<SuggestedVIN/>
<ErrorCode>
0 - VIN decoded clean. Check Digit (9th position) is correct
</ErrorCode>
<PossibleValues/>
<AxleConfiguration/>
<EngineManufacturer>Ford</EngineManufacturer>
<BusLength/>
<BusFloorConfigType/>
<BusType/>
<OtherBusInfo/>
<CustomMotorcycleType/>
<MotorcycleSuspensionType/>
<MotorcycleChassisType/>
<OtherMotorcycleInfo/>
<OtherTrailerInfo/>
<AdditionalErrorText/>
<ManufacturerId>979</ManufacturerId>
<CashForClunkers/>
<TrackWidth/>
</DecodedVINValues>
</Results>
</Response>`;

var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");

//console.dir(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ModelYear")[0].innerHTML);

document.getElementById( "decode_yr" ).innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ModelYear")[0].innerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="decode_yr">
</div>
```

Comment: that not working too..
here is my script
<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
      document.getElementById("decode_yr").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ModelYear")[0].nodeValue;
    }
  };
  var vintodecode = document.getElementById("decode_vinno").value;
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVinValues/"+ vintodecode + "?format=xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

Comment: @Jamal Let me create a demo. Btw, what is the output?

Comment: sorry but still no luck, Iam going crazy now..
here is my code take a look please
https://pastebin.com/f2dSiztj
btw the output is inserted into a <td> innerHTML

Comment: @jamal sorry, I don't have the access to pastebin, can you please share a fiddle or a snippet?

Comment: @Jamal Looks like your xml parsing is failing due to invalid XML being fetched, but demo seems to be working.